# Postgres: Error [42601] Error: Syntax error at or near "$2". Error while executing the Query

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT     
    to_char(messages. TIME, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS FullDate, 
    to_char(messages. TIME, 'MM/DD') AS PartialDate, 
             COUNT(CASE WHEN message_definitions.error_category = ? THEN 1 END) AS Errors, 
    error_categories.threshold, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN messages.message_id = 14 THEN 1 END) AS Picks
FROM    
    messages LEFT JOIN
    message_definitions USING (message_id) LEFT JOIN
    error_categories USING (error_category)
WHERE   
    (messages. TIME > TIMESTAMP ? - '30 day'::INTERVAL) AND 
    (messages. TIME < TIMESTAMP '2016-08-03' + '1 day'::INTERVAL) AND 
    (messages.system_id = ?) AND 
    (messages.message_id = 14 OR
     message_definitions.error_category = ?)
GROUP BY 
    FullDate, PartialDate, error_categories.threshold
ORDER BY
    FullDate DESC LIMIT 40
```

In the above query, In the where clause, (the first line: (messages. TIME > TIMESTAMP ? - '30 day'::INTERVAL) AND 
) when parameter is typecasted (i.e when I put TIMESTAMP before ?) I get the following error

[image]

Which is not true for the text data in the second line   (messages. TIME < **TIMESTAMP**  '2016-08-03' + '1 day'::INTERVAL) AND

When I change the clause to ( messages. TIME > **? ::TIMESTAMP** - '30 day'::INTERVAL) AND 
) 
( i.e I put the TIMESTAMP after ? )
Can anybody throw some light on what is happening?  Thanks!!

Note: 
PostGresVersion - 9.6
OdBC driver - 32 bit driver (located at C:\Program Files (x86)\psqlODBC\0905\bin\psqlodbc30a.dll.)
Same is true with Postgres 8.4 as well.

Comment: Where is the code which binds parameters to the above query?  Are you trying to run the above query verbatim?

Comment: Yes Currently I am running the query verbatim.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) says:

> A constant of an arbitrary type can be entered using any one of the following notations:
>
> `type 'string'`
>   `'string'::type`
>   `CAST ( 'string' AS type )`
>
> The string constant's text is passed to the input conversion routine for the type called type. The result is a constant of the indicated type.
>
> [...]
>
> The `::`, `CAST()`, and function-call syntaxes can also be used to specify run-time type conversions of arbitrary expressions, as discussed in Section 4.2.9. To avoid syntactic ambiguity, the `type 'string'` syntax can only be used to specify the type of a simple literal constant.

So you can use this syntax only with a string literal and not with a parameter as you are trying to do.

Comment: Faced similar problem. Like `time ?` fails but `CAST(? AS time)` works. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the term which you're trying to add, such as the string for example, is supposed to be wrapped in "" . It worked for me, though I can't explain how or why.

Comment: consider adding more information in your answer so others can understand your answer better